# Google Maps - Draggable Marker, unconstrained coordinate values?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps v3, I'm trying to create a map with a marker that is always centered on the map's location. When the marker is draggable, the marker is never replicated on the mirrors of the same map (by that I mean the identical maps you see when at zoom level 1). When dragging of the marker is disabled, it IS replicated on the map mirrors, but then panning the map left & right at zoom:1 eventually results in the marker being covered up by the mirrors. I can't make sense of this behavior so it must be some sort of resource management thing. The real problem, though, is that I'm trying to extract the map/marker's coordinates but the lat/lon values just increase infinitely! There's no limit to the lat/lon values for some reason...

I know for a fact that I ran into this same issue a year ago but I don't remember what the solution was & my code from that project doesn't make it clear what fixed it! I think the fix might have had something to do with LatLngBounds?

```
    $(function(){

    var map = $('#map').gmap3({

        getgeoloc:{

        callback : function(latLng){
        // GEOLOCATION ALLOWED:
          if (latLng){
            $(this).gmap3({
              marker:{
                latLng:latLng,
                options:{
                draggable:false
                },
                events:{
                    dragend: function(marker, event, context){
                    window.currentmarkercenter = marker.getPosition();
                    document.getElementById('markerCoordinates').innerHTML = window.currentmarkercenter;
                    var map = $(this).gmap3("get");
                    map.panTo(window.currentmarkercenter);
                    }
                }
              },
              map:{
              options:{
              center:latLng,
              zoom:14
              },
              events:{
                center_changed: function(map, event, context){
                    window.currentmapcenter = map.getCenter();
                    document.getElementById('markerCoordinates').innerHTML = window.currentmapcenter;
                    var marker = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"marker"}});
                marker.setPosition(window.currentmapcenter);
                    }
                }
              }
            });
            window.geolocation = 1;

          } else {
          //GEOLOCATION DENIED:
          $(this).gmap3({
            marker:{
                latLng:[38.27269,   -96.46094],
                options:{
                draggable:false
                },
                events:{
                    dragend: function(marker, event, context){
                    window.currentmarkercenter = marker.getPosition();
                    document.getElementById('markerCoordinates').innerHTML = window.currentmarkercenter;
                    var map = $(this).gmap3("get");
                    map.panTo(window.currentmarkercenter);
                    }
                }
              },
              map:{
              events:{
                center_changed: function(map, event, context){
                    window.currentmapcenter = map.getCenter();
                    document.getElementById('markerCoordinates').innerHTML = window.currentmapcenter;
                    }
                }
              }
            });
            }
          }
        }
    });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
<div id="markerCoordinates" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:6px;left:42px;"></div>
```

I'm also using http://gmap3.net/en/, a decision I'd be regretting right now except for the fact that when I replace my JS with code from one of its demo files (that puts a marker on the map & lets you pan around), the coordinate values & "map mirroring" works as expected! I'm stumped!